# Can you convert WebGL 3D object to 3D format (fbx, gltf, etc.)?

Tags: webgl, gltf, fbx

We have some legacy WebGL 3D objects that were developed a few years ago that we would like to update. The developer at the time set up the code so that it would read in binary data (a .bin file). From that binary, the geometric data would be parsed by JavaScript code; I think in part using Dataview.js. We no longer have that expertise, so would really like to move these legacy WebGL objects to something like gltf or fbx so that our 3D/graphics guys can more easily modify.

We haven't been able to "open" the binary. So I am looking at what options we have to convert the .bin's to something that we can use.

Comment: If you have the code that renders it you should be able to see how it reads the data, intercept, and then write it into some well known simple file format like OBJ, doing so is not really in the scope for stackoverflow though as it's asking for a case specific solution that will not be helpful for others, making this more of a job advert than a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a WebGL object unfortunately. And without knowing if the project using another library like threejs, or raw WebGL, it is difficult to infer how the object was processed.

If threejs was used, it most likely was converted to Threejs geometry format, in which case it could be exported to a gltf. But it may still require a fair amount of investigation to find where to trigger this export from.

Comment: I know it's not Threejs data because it is not calling Threejs code. But more likely it is using raw WebGL looking at what the JavaScript is doing in the background to create the model. From my best guess, the .bin file contains a dataset of the geometry and is parsed using DataView.js. Thanks!

Comment: ok, good to know. In that case, I'd give a try with Spectorjs ( https://spector.babylonjs.com/ ) to inspect what is sent to the gpu.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you convert WebGL 3D object to 3D format (fbx, gltf, etc.)?

You can use debugger and override functions such as `drawElements`, `drawArrays`, texture bindings and more to catch all data consumed by webgl program.

Now it depends what does shaders do with given data. In case of very straightforward simple shaders, data that you extracted can be probably simply converted to models.

Some websites like sketchfab that are selling 3d models are obfuscating data by increasing complexity of shaders. Certain code doesn't need to be there for application logic, it is there only to prevent data extraction. Then models can be still ghatered if shader transformations are applied on data extracted from buffers. It is just harder.